# Substrings after 3 underscores and before a dot in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a some strings like below in `Linux`.

```
abc_def_fgh_2018_08_11.zip
```

I want to extract just `2018_08_11` as a variable. All the strings have the same pattern `3 underscores` and `some dates or characters` and `.zip`

How can I do that?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$ foo='abc_def_fgh_2018_08_11.zip'
$ foo=${foo#*_*_*_}                   # remove the prefix
$ echo "${foo%.*}"                    # remove the sufix and print
2018_08_11
```

---

Or using regular expression:

```
$ foo='abc_def_fgh_2018_08_11.zip'
$ regex='^([^_]*_){3}(.*)\.' 
$ [[ $foo =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
2018_08_11
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is a special array where the matches from `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` are assigned to.

Comment: Look at the comment on the question, then add 1+1 - jww thinks that answers to what he considers off-topic questions must be downvoted. I like to think that it backfires when people upvote just to compensate.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Hm, I didn't upvote the question if that's what you are implying...I agree to some extent, OP should've showed some effort. Although, there are MANY questions here that don't show any research effort either and are answered with no problems or downvotes. My point is: what's the big deal with posting an answer with sources for further study that takes like 30 seconds to write when OP might have been struggling for hours...people should just relax a little and help each other :)

Comment: Ah, no no, I didn't want to imply that - I'm totally with you. I think downvoting a good answer to a bad question is wrong, and people who do so all the time might actually cause other people to upvote to undo the unjust downvote, so the downvote might have the opposite effect of what was intended. See also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459) and the opposing view [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963), and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368711), especially its revision history.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I misunderstood your comment, sorry! The linked questions were very interesting to read and I agree with you completely.